# Просмотр страницы чужих визиток

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос один: баг или так задумано?

Имеется возможность перейти по URL и посмотреть чужие визитки, хотя ссылка на эту страницу(просмотра **СВОИХ** визиток) есть только при редактировании своего профиля.

В профилях других пользователей нигде прямой ссылки на эту страницу нет, тем не менее её можно увидеть

**Как пример:**
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183450/maksim/flair

Comment: Как бы там прятать особо нечего, так что ничего страшного что по прямой ссылке можно пройти. Это как бы и не баг, и не фича, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut по поводу фичи это я неправильно выразился

Comment: Сути не меняет. Вряд ли задумано, чтобы на эту страницу ходили другие.

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, там можно имя, аватарку и всю информацию редактировать! Стоп... или это только для модераторов? :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня такой возможности нет, дай аккаунт погонять)

Comment: @NickVolynkin там бы надо ещё плашку для объединённой анкеты локализовать.